# Multithreaded program to measure the performance of service

Tags: java, multithreading

I am in the process of measuing the performance of our service. So I have a URL that will make the call to our service. So what I did is that before making the call to the service, I make a note of the time and after the response came back from the service, I measure the response time. I wrote a program that was making the call to my service and measuring the performance by putting the numbers in a HashMap-

```
    while (runs > 0) {

        long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = restTemplate.getForObject("Some URL", String.class);
        long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);

        Long count = histogram.get(difference);
        if (count != null) {
            count++;
            histogram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), count);
        } else {
            histogram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), Long.valueOf(1L));
        }
        runs--;
    }
```

So output I will be getting from the histogram map will be- `X number of calls came back in Y ms`

Now what I was thinking instead of making a single call at a time, why not I should parallelize the calls to our service, like in my previous program, I am hitting the service one by one. So I wrote a 
multithreading program below which will make a call to my service simultaneously. So the below program will be able to measure the time difference accurately or not?

**Like one thread is taking this much time, second thread is taking this much time, third thread is taking this much time and so on? Is it possible to do this?**

If yes, can anyone tell me how to do it if my below program doesn't work very well?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1 * 2; i++) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask(i));
    }
    service.shutdown();
    try {
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private String result;
    private HashMap<Long, Long> histogram;

    public ThreadTask(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        result = restTemplate.getForObject("Some URL",String.class);
        long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);

        Long count = histogram.get(difference);
        if (count != null) {
            count++;
            histogram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), count);
        } else {
            histogram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), Long.valueOf(1L));
        }

        System.out.println(histogram);
    }
}
```

Because whenever I run the program, the numbers I am getting from this multithreading program looks very weird.

**Output I got from Non Multithreading Program**

```
168=1
41=1
43=3
```

`1 call came back in 168 ms` and so on...

**And output I got from Multithreading program**

```
{119=1}
{179=1}
{150=1}
{202=1}
{149=1}
```

`1 call came back in 119 ms` and so on...
 So in the multithreaded program, it is taking lot more time I guess?

Comment: What numbers are you getting? How are they weird?

Comment: First of all I am not sure, the above program I have wrote will do what I want or not? Currently I am running two threads only. So my above program will do something like this or not- `One thread has taken this much time, Second thread takes this much time` I will put the numbers in question

Comment: It does seem to take more time with multiple threads, but I don't know why. In the multithreaded version, each thread is has only one iterations. Since each thread has its own histogram, they will all have 1 entry each. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but it might be possible that two threads can take similar time? Right? If you take a look at my `run method`, I am adding the count variable every time if there is a match

Comment: Yes, but each `ThreadTask` has its *own* histogram. You can make histogram a `class static variable` to get the functionality you want, but in that case you will also need `static synchronized` method to update the map concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: Can you provide me an example for that to achieve the above functionality? By that I can understand how to do that..

Comment: If you're measuring distance between 2 points in time and are not interested in the actual time, you should really use `System.nanoTime()` since it is much much more precise.

Comment: And if you're really interested in measuring performance, check out this great talk on why what you're doing will likely give you irrelevant results if you're not very careful: http://www.parleys.com/play/514892280364bc17fc56c04a/chapter6/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean by getting weird numbers. My wild guess is that it is because output from different threads is getting interspersed.

One way to solve it is to not print the `histogram` from the `run` method at all. It is already an instance variable (though it currently does not need to be) so you can:

1. Instead of submitting unnamed instances of `ThreadTask` store them in a list/array.
2. Create a method `ThreadTask.report` that prints the `histogram`
3. After all the threads have completed, call `ThreadTask.report` on each *in sequence*.

Comment: Thanks Miserable for the suggestion. I have updated the question as well. Can you provide me what changes I need to make in my code with your first point I was not able to understand. From an example I can understand that more better. And how do I make sure all threads have compeleted as well? Any example will make me understand me better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accounting for the same time multiple times. If your threads do not execute this part of the code within a synchronized block:

```
long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

result = restTemplate.getForObject("Some URL",String.class);
long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);
```

then it is possible for this to happen:

1. Thread1: long start_time ...
2. Thread1: result = ...
3. Thread2: long start_time ...
4. Thread2: result = ...
5. Thread2: long difference ...
6. Thread1: long difference ...

So your accounting will not work properly. You could use synchronized blocks or look into Java's [`java.lang.management`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html) (e.g., `ThreadMXBean` and `ThreadInfo`), for timing functionality in threaded environments.

**Update:**

Also see the answer to [this related SO question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800573/timing-a-remote-call-in-a-multithreaded-java-program) on the problem and how to go around it.