# Timing a remote call in a multithreaded java program

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking

I am writing a stress test that will issue many calls to a remote server. I want to collect the following statistics after the test:

1. Latency (in milliseconds) of the remote call.
2. Number of operations per second that the remote server can handle.

I can successfully get (2), but I am having problems with (1). My current implementation is very similar to the one shown in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617448/multithreaded-program-to-measure-the-performance-of-service/). And I have the same problem described in that question: latency reported by using `System.currentTimeMillis()` is longer than expected when the test is run with multiple threads.

I analyzed the problem and I am positive the problem comes from the thread interleaving (see my answer to the other question that I linked above for details), and that `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not the way to solve this problem.

It seems that I should be able to do it using `java.lang.management`, which has some interesting methods like:

1. `ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime()`
2. `ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadUserTime()`
3. `ThreadInfo.getWaitedTime()`
4. `ThreadInfo.getBlockedTime()`

My problem is that even though I have read the API, it is still unclear to me which of these methods will give me what I want. In the context of the other SO question that I linked, this is what I need:

```
long start_time = **rightMethodToCall()**;

result = restTemplate.getForObject("Some URL",String.class);
long difference = (**rightMethodToCall()** - start_time);
```

So that the `difference` gives me a very good approximation of the time that the remote call took, even in a multi-threaded environment.

Restriction: I'd like to avoid protecting that block of code with a `synchronized` block because my program has other threads that I would like to allow to continue executing.

EDIT: Providing more info.:

The issue is this: I want to time the remote call, and just the remote call. If I use `System.currentTimeMillis` or `System.nanoTime()`, AND if I have more threads than cores, then it is possible that I could have this thread interleaving:

1. Thread1: long start_time ...
2. Thread1: result = ...
3. Thread2: long start_time ...
4. Thread2: result = ...
5. Thread2: long difference ...
6. Thread1: long difference ...

If that happens, then the difference calculated by Thread2 is correct, but the one calculated by Thread1 is incorrect (it would be greater than it should be). In other words, for the measurement of the difference in Thread1, I would like to exclude the time of lines 4 and 5. Is this time that the thread was WAITING?

Summarizing question in a different way in case it helps other people understand it better (this quote is how @jason-c put it in his comment.):

**[I am] attempting to time the remote call, but running the test with multiple threads just to increase testing volume.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.nanoTime()` (but see updates at end of this answer).

You definitely don't want to use the current thread's CPU or user time, as user-perceived latency is wall clock time, not thread CPU time. You also don't want to use the current thread's blocking or waiting time, as it measures per-thread contention times which also doesn't accurately represent what you are trying to measure.

`System.nanoTime()` will return relatively accurate results (although granularity is technically only guaranteed to be as good or better than `currentTimeMillis()`, in practice it tends to be much better, generally implemented with hardware clocks or other performance timers, e.g. `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows or `clock_gettime` on Linux) from a high resolution clock with a fixed reference point, and will measure exactly what you are trying to measure.

```
long start_time = System.nanoTime();
result = restTemplate.getForObject("Some URL",String.class);
long difference = (System.nanoTime() - start_time);
long milliseconds = difference / 1000000;
```

`System.nanoTime()` does have it's [own set of issues](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html) but be careful not to get whipped up in paranoia; for most applications it is more than adequate. You just wouldn't want to use it for, say, precise timing when sending audio samples to hardware or something (which you wouldn't do directly in Java anyways).

**Update 1:**

More importantly, how do you know the measured values are longer than expected? If your measurements are showing true wall clock time, and some threads are taking longer than others, that is still an *accurate representation of user-perceived latency*, as some users *will* experience those longer delay times.

**Update 2 (based on clarification in comments):**

Much of my above answer is still valid then; but for different reasons.

Using per-thread time does not give you an accurate representation because a thread could be idle/inactive while the remote request is still processing, and you would therefore exclude that time from your measurement even though it is part of perceived latency.

Further inaccuracies are introduced by the remote server taking longer to process the simultaneous requests you are making - this is an extra variable that you are adding (although it may be acceptable as representative of the remote server being busy).

Wall time is also not completely accurate because, as you have seen, variances in local thread overhead may add extra latency that isn't typically present in single-request client applications (although this still may be acceptable as representative of a client application that is multi-threaded, but it is a variable you cannot control).

Of those two, wall time will still get you closer to the actual result than per-thread time, which is why I left the previous answer above. You have a few options:

- You could do your tests on a single thread, serially -- *this is ultimately the most accurate way to achieve your stated requirements*.
- You could not create more threads than cores, e.g. a fixed size thread pool with bound affinities (tricky: [Java thread affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238272/java-thread-affinity)) to each core and measurements running as tasks on each. Of course this still adds any variables due to synchronization of underlying mechanisms that are beyond your control. This *may* reduce the risk of interleaving (especially if you set the affinities) but you still do not have full control over e.g. other threads the JVM is running or other unrelated processes on the system.
- You could measure the request handling time on the remote server; of course this does not take network latency into account.
- You could continue using your current approach and do some statistical analysis on the results to remove outliers.
- You could not measure this at all, and simply do user tests and wait for a comment on it before attempting to optimize it (i.e. measure it with people, who are what you're developing for anyways). If the only reason to optimize this is for UX, it could very well be the case that users have a pleasant experience and the wait time is totally acceptable.

Also, none of this makes any guarantees that other unrelated threads on the system won't be affecting your timings, but that is why it is important to both a) run your test multiple times and average (obviously) and b) set an acceptable requirement for timing error's that you are OK with (do you *really* need to know this to e.g. 0.1ms accuracy?).

Personally, I would either do the first, single-threaded approach and let it run overnight or over a weekend, or use your existing approach and remove outliers from the result and accept a margin of error in the timings. Your goal is to find a *realistic estimate* within a *satisfactory* margin of error. You will also want to consider what you are going to ultimately do with this information when deciding what is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I did not know about `System.nanoTime()`. However, I think that my use of "user-perceived" was ambiguous, so I removed it from the question. I also added a better explanation of my problem at the end of the question.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original question then. Just to be clear; are you attempting to time the remote call, but running the test with multiple threads just to increase testing volume?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! I am sorry that my question was not clear enough.

Comment: I have updated the above answer (I left the original, new comments added to end).

Comment: Ah, very interesting. I suppose out of your suggestions, the one about measuring at the server is the most close one to what I want. The reason I use threads (and actually multiple computers running the same multi-threaded code at the same time) is that I WANT to overload the server and see how that affects response time. I use threading to simulate a larger number of clients with a few (~30) computers. Removing threading would not allow me to do that.

Comment: You could perhaps have one or more computers running many, many threads, with the sole purpose of making the server busy, while one or more others are doing single-threaded timing tests. Of course there is still the variable that your local network bandwidth is likely higher than you may get in a real setup, but that may be negligible or acceptable for you, especially if transfer times are a negligible portion of the total wait time.

Comment: If you used the total "waiting" time you would have to be sure that the thread was actually in the WAITING state throughout the entire request (you cannot guarantee that unless you can guarantee that no library or native calls in `getForObject()` take it out of that state, which you likely can't) and it would also be subject to any additional interleaving overhead that kept the thread WAITING outside of the remote request window. It's all very tricky and nondeterministic, which is why I also suggested increasing your acceptable margin of error. :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING for your reference.

Comment: I added one more option: You could not measure this at all, and simply do user tests and observe comments on it before attempting to optimize it (i.e. measure it with people, who are what you're developing for anyways). If the only reason to optimize this is for UX, it could very well be the case that users have a pleasant experience and the wait time is totally acceptable, with your efforts best spent elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this is not premature optimization :-) I am doing scalability tests and wanted to see when the service performance starts degrading. My test is not showing that. I'll have to figure out a different way of doing this.

Comment: Have you checked out something like http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/ or http://jmeter.apache.org/?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out.